# repopulating table with "filtered" data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, regex

See the code below.

I have a table populated with JSON data. The following is intended to clear the table and retrieve *only* the data with the last name criteria specified by the user.

So far, I'm successful in creating the filter criteria and wiping the table clean. However, I'm having trouble repopulating the table with the filtered results.

Possible hang-ups:

-the Regex: I'm new to RegExp with JS and I'm thinking the syntax is correct, but I'm not entirely sure. I'm also not sure if I'm able to use it the way I am (setting it: `filterCriteria = new RegExp("^" + filter.value)` and then calling on it to check if last_name object is equal to it: `if (contacts.last_name  === filterCriteria)`

- or even if the Regex is working properly, am I able to create a new array based on it the way I'm trying to in that If statement? I.e. is that enough to say, "Take only the objects with a last name that matches the criteria and throw them into a new array"?

Thanks for the help!

```
var filter = document.getElementById("filter");
    filter.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ((xhr.readyState === 4) && (xhr.status === 200)) {
                var contacts = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).data,
                    filterCriteria = new RegExp("^" + filter.value),
                    i;
                for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i += 1) {
                    var contactTableBody = document.getElementById("contactTable").lastElementChild,
                        lastRow = contactTableBody.lastElementChild;
                    contactTableBody.removeChild(lastRow);
                }
                if (contacts.last_name  === filterCriteria) {
                    var filterResults = [contacts];
                    for (i = 0; i < contacts.length; i += 1) {
                        contactTableBody = document.getElementById("contactTable").lastElementChild;
                        var newRow = [],
                            newNameCell = document.createElement("td"),
                            newPhoneCell = document.createElement("td"),
                            newEmailCell = document.createElement("td"),
                            newNameNode = document.createTextNode(contacts[i].last_name + ", " + contacts[i].first_name),
                            newPhoneNode = document.createTextNode(contacts[i].phone),
                            newEmailNode = document.createTextNode(contacts[i].email);

                        newRow[i] = document.createElement("tr");
                        newRow[i].id = "contact" + i;
                        newNameCell.appendChild(newNameNode);
                        newPhoneCell.appendChild(newPhoneNode);
                        newEmailCell.appendChild(newEmailNode);
                        newRow[i].appendChild(newNameCell);
                        newRow[i].appendChild(newPhoneCell);
                        newRow[i].appendChild(newEmailCell);
                        contactTableBody.appendChild(newRow[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

EDIT:

not 100% on the brace/bracket notation but that should give an idea on how the data is oriented

```
contacts = JSON.parse(XMLHttpResponse.responseText).data  = { [
    { "first_name":"Jim", "last_name":"Cooper", "phone":"8435555555", "email":"jim@halpert.com" },
    { "first_name":"Jim", "last_name":"Aaron", "phone":"1234567890", "email":"jim@beam.com" },
    { "first_name":"Mark", "last_name":"Smith", "phone":"4567891236", "email":"mark@smith.com" },
    { "first_name":"Sally", "last_name":"Smith", "phone":"5469876622", "email":"sally@smith.com" },
    { "first_name":"Mary", "last_name":"Coppersmith", "phone":"6854895212", "email":"mary@coppersmith.com" }        
] }
```

Comment: I do not know the context, but shouldnt the ```contacts.last_name``` be inside the for loop? Something like this ```contacts[i].last_name == filterCriteria```. If you can the mock up data for contact or a jsfiddle, it would help.

Comment: @Santosh see edits. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please provide an HTML output, so that it will be more easier for us to read. You can check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Jeroinmo the json structure for the contacts is an array of objects containing first and last name. But you are checking the condition ```contacts.last_name === filterCriteria```. Also are using a for loop to remove the each (last) row of the contacts Table?

Comment: @Santosh you had it right, it was the for loop... that got me moving in the right direction, thanks.

I was going to try to put together a fiddle, but then I got it working all of a sudden. I'll try to be more prepared the next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from Santosh initial comment:

> I do not know the context, but shouldnt the `contacts.last_name` be
>   inside the for loop? Something like this `contacts[i].last_name == filterCriteria`. If you can the mock up data for contact or a jsfiddle,
>   it would help.

It was in fact a `for` loop that was needed. Thanks.